# std::array error: Has no member named 'assign'

Tags: c++, c++11, assign, g++4.8, stdarray

In the following code, the compiler complains as: `struct std::array<double,5ul> has no member named 'assign'`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982277.aspx), it seems possible. Why is it so? (Compiler: g++ 4.8.2)

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<double,5> arr;
    arr.assign(4.); // error: has no member named 'assign'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why class template `std::array` has no `assign` member function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is very simple, as you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) there is no assign member function for an std array. There is however a member function called `fill` you should be able to use.

Answer (score 14):

`array::assign()` is a Visual Studio extension. You are compiling with g++. Check here [standard g++ array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: s/standard g++/standard C++/

Comment: Why why? what is the need of this extension? .. +1 BTW

Comment: @Nawaz It helps stop the error message "has no member named 'assign'".

Answer (score 9):

As already mentioned, there simply is no `assign` member to `std::array`.

The interesting question now becomes *why* ? After all, the other containers have an `assign` member method !

I would note that unlike other containers, `std::array` has a fixed size. If you use `std::vector<T>::assign` (which would be a close equivalent), the vector is resized appropriately to match the size of the sequence being assigned; with an array, however, that would be impossible:

- what would you do if the sequence being assigned is shorter than the array ?
- what would you do if the sequence being assigned is longer than the array ?

this would be counter-intuitive, as the question does not arise for the other containers since their size is just adapted on the fly.

For a similar reason, `std::array` does not have: `reserve`, `capacity`, `clear`, `insert`, `emplace`, `erase`, `push`/`pop` (and variants) or `resize`. All of them suppose a container which size may vary.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. In fact, you are answering the question I *thought* OP might have been asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza I must say that this is one VS extension that looks kinda handy though. I wasn't aware that it existed, but looking at it now, all it does is call `fill_n` to set all elements to the input argument.

Comment: @Praetorian But there's also `std::array::fill` for that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Haha, ok, never mind, back to being a silly extension then :)

Answer (score 2):

The `assign` method it is not a member of `std::array`. The member `fill` does what the `assign` did in TR1.

`assign` was originally part of `std::tr1::array` (from [the TR1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf)) and was changed to be `fill` circa the C++0x (now C++11) [draft n2798](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf) (2008).

This is not really a Microsoft extension, I would imagine that they have probably maintained this method for compatibility with, and support for `tr1` implementations in production (the method implementations are exactly the same).